# How to make an executable for a python project

Tags: linux, jar, python-2.7

Sorry if my title is not correct. Below is the explanation of what i'm looking for.

I've coded a small GUI game (let say a snake game) in python, and I want it to be run on Linux machine. I can run this program by just run command "python snake.py" in the terminal.

However, I want to combine all my .py files into one file, and when I click on this file, it just run my game. I don't want to go to shell and type "python snake.py". I means something like manifest .jar in java.

Could any one help me please? If my explanation is not good enough, please let me know. I'll give some more explanation.

Comment: I am not very executed about this question's title.

Comment: You can create a .desktop file to run your game.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) for Unix, or [py2exe](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe) for Windows.

[cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/),  [bbfreeze](http://www.jroller.com/alessiopace/entry/python_standalone_executables_with_bbfreeze) and [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) - which I have never tried - are also available for various platforms, so there are many options.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want it to run on a Linux machine, using Python eggs is the simplest way.

python snake.egg will try to execute the **main**.py inside the egg.

Python eggs are meant to be packages, and basically is a zip file with metadata files included.